# Adding existing Host to SCVMM: Error 2912

Tags: hyper-v, virtual-machines, scvmm, winrm

When trying to add an existing Hyper-V-Host to SCVMM I get the following error:

> Error (2912)
> An internal error has occurred trying to contact an agent on the %serverName%.
> (Unknown error (0x80041004))
>
> Recommendation Action
> Ensure that the agent is installed and running. Ensure the WS-Management service is installed and running, then restart the agent.

The host used to be managed by SCVMM before without any problems. I removed it and tried to add it to the manager again, because suddenly the status was `"Host not responding"` for all hosted VMs (even though they're up and running).

The `VMAgent` and `WinRM` services on the host are running and restarting them didn't help. A reboot of the SCVMM-Server didn't help either.

A reboot of the VM host is scheduled, let's see if that helps. I keep you posted.

**UPDATE**

According to MSDN the error code means **WBEM_E_PROVIDER_FAILURE** ("Provider has failed at some time other than during initialization") in WMI.

Comment: Have you validated the host is reachable? Could that be similar to the usual beginner SQL Server issue - host can not be reached because.... the firewall blocks access to it? If a policy blocks the necessary ports.... then this could be an error contacting an agent.

Comment: The host *is* reachable (PING etc.). It can even still be managed with Hyper-V-Manager. I strongly doubt that it's just a firewall issue, because it used to work before and this issue seems to have come out of nowhere. Besides, this host (and the other host I have exactly the same problem with) is configured exactly the same as all the other VM-hosts, which are still working fine.

Comment: Ping is not the same as the ports for the agent being open. With SQL Server that is a well known trap for beginner admins. For example, my group policies here allow ping to all machines. They also disallow any real traffic that is not needed. None would have the agent ports open. If that is not the case - any hing from the event logs on that machine?

Answer (score -1):

Try to rebuild WMI performance counters

lodctr /R

Helps me in the same situation. Error is pretty common.

Comment: Why does [Mikhail Bozhnev's answer](http://serverfault.com/a/722633/359642 "lodctr /R") have a low score? Running **lodctr /R** on my afflicted host definitely fixed error 2912 for me when managing the host in SCVMM. Thank you!